# For a mixture of experts model, are the experts trained independently first or trained w.r.t their summed output * gate weights?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I've seen a few examples that train a Mixture of Experts model at once (one iteration backprops on the entire gated+m.o.e network). However this only works for models that can be optimized in this way. E.g say one expert is a knn classifier and the other is a standard mlp.

So is the loss calculated with respect to each expert and then the gating network is optimized itself or is the total loss computed w.r.t. the gated weights * expert outputs?

Comment: I can imagine either scenario working.  Are you asking which is better or what are the consequences?  If you optimize the experts then the gating network then each expert will try and be a generalist.  If you optimize using gated weights then the experts will only get trained on what they were good at, which will make them specialize.  *I am only speculating here, I don't have a reference* but I think it will drive a difference between a m.o.e. of generalists vs specialists.

Answer (score 1):

[Elaborating @Wontonimo answer]

In a Mixture of Experts network, for every input each expert provides its own output, which is then weighted by the Gating Network.

During training, each Expert receives the correct output and a coefficient (typically in [0,1]), which will be proportional to the quality of its output previously given to that specific input.

The Gating Network dynamically partitions the input space into (fuzzy) subsets to be assigned to the Experts.

This allows each Expert to specialize on a subset of the possible input values.

The Expert networks and the Gating networks had better be trained simultaneously, since their updates are interdependent.